# print out tiles from command line argument

Tags: python, arguments, command, line, tiles

I need to print out tiles based on command line arguments in which first argument is the width and second is the name. 
for example:

```
$ python tile.py 5 tommy
------+|+------
---+|++|++|+---
-----TOMMY-----
---+|++|++|+---
------+|+------
```

or

```
$ python tile.py 7 Samuel 
---------+|+---------
------+|++|++|+------
---+|++|++|++|++|+---
--------SAMUEL-------
---+|++|++|++|++|+---
------+|++|++|+------
---------+|+---------
```

as there are some restriction: width can only be odd, and the length of the name cannot exceed 3*width.

I am confused how to do the vertical part as it can be 5, 7, or more layers

```
import sys
a = int(sys.argv[1])
if a%2==0:
    print('Error: tile height must be an odd number')
else:
    if len(sys.argv[2])>(3*a):
        print('Error: name must fit within {} characters'.format(3*a))
    else:
        print('-'*((3*a-3)/2)+'+-+'+'-'*((3*a-3)/2))
        print('-'*((3*a-9)/2))
```

Comment: it seems to me that the width and height is always the same, since you alwasy decrease the number of '-' by 2, until a min of 3 are left, so for width=9, one line would have 9 '-' one would have 7, then 5, then 3, thats 4 lines, then one line for the name, and 4 again in reverse order, so thats 9 total

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string function [`str.center`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.center) to simplify the padding. Other than that you just use a loop to count up and then down, leveraging pythons [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) and `*` operator on lists:

```
#        Growing width       Name    Shrinking width
widths = list(range(a//2)) + [-1] + list(reversed(range(a//2)))
for k in widths:
    # Print name if we're halfway there
    if k == -1: 
        # Print name in uppercase, centered over 3*a characters, padded with '-'
        print(name.upper().center(3*a,'-'))
    else:
        # Repeat '+|+' 1+2k number of times, 
        # join with nothing in between and center, padding with '-'
        print("".join(["+|+"]*(1+2*k)).center(3*a,'-'))
```